# Trying to convert hash function to C

Tags: c, hash

I saw this hash function and would like to convert it to C.  Having a problem with the .substring and toCharArray()

```
long sfold(String s, int M) 
{
   int intLength = s.length() / 4;
   long sum = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j < intLength; j++) 
   {
      char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
      long mult = 1;
      for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) 
      {
         sum += c[k] * mult;
         mult *= 256;
      }
   }

   char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
   long mult = 1;
   for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) 
   {
      sum += c[k] * mult;
      mult *= 256;
   }

   return(Math.abs(sum) % M);
}
```

I've made the following changes:

```
long sfold(char* s, int M) 
{
   int intLength = strlen(s) / 4;
   long sum = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j < intLength; j++) 
   {
      char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
      long mult = 1;
      for (int k = 0; k < strlen(c); k++) 
      {
         sum += c[k] * mult;
         mult *= 256;
      }
   }

   char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
   long mult = 1;
   for (int k = 0; k < strlen(c); k++) 
   {
      sum += c[k] * mult;
      mult *= 256;
   }

   return(Math.abs(sum) % M);
}
```

these are the two lines I'm having trouble with:

```
char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
```

could some explain what these two lines are doing?

Comment: What about `c.length`? That's not C too. Use `strlen(c)`

Comment: There is a lot of nonsense code, which is not C. It is either pseudo code or some other language.

Comment: @Lundin it's probably Java, and the title reads _convert to C_.

Comment: That's really not a very good hash code algorithm. There are some better (and simple) ones [here](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo It is not Java, it is not C, it is not C++.

Comment: @Lundin look better: the first one is almost surely Java, while the second is an unfinished attempt at porting Java to C, with some Java-esque features still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is reading chunks of four characters per time to an array:

```
char c[] = s.substring(j * 4, (j * 4) + 4).toCharArray();
```

you could replace it with:

```
char c[4];
memcpy(c, s + 4*j, 4);
```

The second one is copying the rest of the string, from the largest multiple of 4 smaller than `strlen(s)` to the end, since:

```
int intLength = strlen(s) / 4;
```

and therefore:

```
char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
```

is just:

```
char c[strlen(s)];
memcpy(c, s + intLength*4, strlen(s) - 4*intLength);
```

At this point, you should precalculate `strlen(s)` and store it in a variable, since strings in C do not actually exist (they are just arrays of `char` whose last element is `\0`) and each call to `strlen` implies that the whole string has to be scanned for the `\0`, in order to determine the length.

However, **all those copies are not even necessary, since you are not modifying `s`**, so you just have to adjust the indexes in the loops and you can skip the `memcpy` altogether:

```
long sfold(const char* s, size_t length, long M) {
   size_t intLength = length / 4;

   long sum = 0;

   for (size_t j = 0; j < intLength; j++) {
      long mult = 1;
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
         sum += s[j*4 + k] * mult;
         mult *= 256;
      }
   }

   long mult = 1;
   for (size_t k = intLength*4; k < length; k++) {
      sum += s[k] * mult;
      mult *= 256;
   }

   return labs(sum) % M;
}
```

Comment: I voted you up as the memcpy worked.  I notice that c[] is addressed in the bottom for loop so the second memcpy needs to be done.  also, you use length_of_s but that should be intLength or am I missing something?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: That was just to convey the idea without copying the exact code (which would have been a little more obscure). If you want to further optimize, note that you don't even need the `memcpy`.